# Magento 2.1.9 override catalog rule form

Tags: magento2

I need to make some changes in catalog_rule_form.xml based on Magento_CatalogRule/view/adminhtml/ui_component/catalog_rule_form.xml

I tried to override this file in custom module and place new file in view/adminhtml/ui_component/catalog_rule_form.xml
Module has sequence declaration in module.xml like this:

```
    <sequence>
        <module name="Magento_CatalogRule"/>
    </sequence>
```

does not work.
Also i tried to place it in app/design/adminhtml/Vendor/Theme/Magento_CatalogRule/ui_component/catalog_rule_form.xml
same result.

Does anyone could help me with this. How can i override this form?